# Group and concatenate List of tuples

Tags: c#, linq, ienumerable

I have a list of pairs (key, val) with both key and value being strings. I want to aggregate the tuples with duplicate keys.

```
For (key1, val1), (key2, val2), (key3, val3), (key1, val4), (key2, val5)
```

I want output

```
(key1, val1+val4), (key2, val2+val5)
```

This is my current query

```
var duplicates = Contents.Records.SelectMany(x => x.Users).Select(x => new { Name = x.Name, ID= x.ID}).GroupBy(x => x.ID).Select(x => new { x.Key, Names = x.Select(p=>p.Name).Aggregate((a,b) => a +","+b)}).ToArray();
```

But at the end for each entry in duplicates the member Names is empty.

The data is as follows each Records has a List Users. Each user has a Name and an ID.
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not see an obvious flaw in your grouping and selection, and can indeed run that against a sample set of data and get what I believe to be your desired results. Have you checked the inputs to verify that the data you expect is loaded? For example, split the query and perform a `ToList()` after `.SelectMany(...).Select(...)`. Does your data look as you expect it to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Aggregate` looks like it should do the job. But I've never liked `Aggregate`. The syntax is not intuitive (in my mind). Usually other ways look more lucid. Take this one:

```
Tuple<string,string>[] tuples = { 
                                    Tuple.Create("key1", "val1"), 
                                    Tuple.Create("key2", "val2"), 
                                    Tuple.Create("key3", "val3"), 
                                    Tuple.Create("key1", "val4"), 
                                    Tuple.Create("key2", "val5")
                                };
tuples.GroupBy(t => t.Item1, t => t.Item2)
      .Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key, string.Join("+", g)))
      .Dump(); // Linqpad output command
```

result:

```
key1    val1+val4
key2    val2+val5
key3    val3
```