# Split a Tuple List to separate groups based on Item1

Tags: c#, list, tuples

i am having trouble with seperating a tuple list to different groups, based on the Item1 of the tuple in list (Each group basically should have the same Item1)

Code:

```
        static List<Tuple<string, string, string>> myList = new List<Tuple<string, string, string>>();
        myList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>("GroupA", "", ""));
        myList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>("GroupA", "", ""));
        myList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>("GroupB", "", ""));
        myList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>("GroupB", "", ""));
        myList.Add(new Tuple<string, string, string>("GroupC", "", ""));
```

What i want to do than, is seperate those added items to groups, (basically make another 3 Tuple Lists based, Group A, B, C).

Comment: Hi! i am not quite sure i get it, the input could be anything, I have one big Tuple List that contains all the groups (Groups are determined by Item1)
Items in the list that the Tuple item1 is the same, should be split into a different List Tuple, that contains only that specific group.

Comment: The point is I don't understand your question. If you show some sample inputs and outputs then it will help to understand what you are asking for...

Comment: here is a link  you can read up on about how to group a [List<Tuple>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093395/group-and-concatenate-list-of-tuples)

Comment: Thanks @MethodMan will check it out, although for now i just figured i would sort the list by Item1 instead of separating it

Answer (score 1):

You can group the elements by `Item1`

```
var lists = myList.GroupBy(c => c.Item1);
```

Comment: Whats the difference between this and OrderBy?

Comment: This will create a collection of collections. `OrderBy` will just create a new collection that has the items arranged by some property.