# Tuple<string,string> with a GroupBy

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `Tuple<string,string>`

In this tuple, I can Have this:

```
"<GOOD>10</GOOD>","5"
"<GOOD>TEST</GOOD>","8"
"<GOOD>TEMP</GOOD>","5"
"<GOOD>CAT</GOOD>","7"
"<GOOD>DOG</GOOD>","7"
```

I want to group all the firt item of the tuple and have this in a dictionnary:

```
"5","<GOOD>10</GOOD><GOOD>TEMP</GOOD>"
"8","<GOOD>TEST</GOOD>"
"7","<GOOD>CAT</GOOD><GOOD>DOG</GOOD>"
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [c# Group and then Sort list of tuple <T1,T2,T3>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38916084/c-sharp-group-and-then-sort-list-of-tuple-t1-t2-t3) and [Group and concatenate List of tuples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16093395/group-and-concatenate-list-of-tuples)

Comment: What do you have so far? `YourList.GroupBy(t => t.Item1).Select(g => Tuple.Create(g.Key, string.Concat(g))` maybe?

Comment: Upvoting Linq solution. Linq <3

Answer (score 2):

A `Tuple<T1,T2>` can only have one item for `T1` and one item for `T2`. Assuming you have a *collection* of `Tuple<string, string>`, you may use the following:

```
var dict = tuples.GroupBy(t => t.Item2)
                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => string.Concat(g.Select(t => t.Item1)));
```

Here's a full example:

```
var tuples = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();

tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("<GOOD>10</GOOD>", "5"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("<GOOD>TEST</GOOD>", "8"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("<GOOD>TEMP</GOOD>", "5"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("<GOOD>CAT</GOOD>", "7"));
tuples.Add(Tuple.Create("<GOOD>DOG</GOOD>", "7"));

var dict = tuples.GroupBy(t => t.Item2)
                 .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => string.Concat(g.Select(t => t.Item1)));
```

**[Try it online](https://rextester.com/COXAS32748)**.

Note that this will also work with [ValueTuples](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=net-5.0). Here's an [example](https://rextester.com/UJOKR31498).

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to `GroupBy()` you can use `ToLookup()`. It doesn't really make any difference to the efficiency, but just so you are aware:

```
public static void Main()
{
    (string, string)[] tuples = 
    {
        ("<GOOD>10</GOOD>",   "5"),
        ("<GOOD>TEST</GOOD>", "8"),
        ("<GOOD>TEMP</GOOD>", "5"),
        ("<GOOD>CAT</GOOD>",  "7"),
        ("<GOOD>DOG</GOOD>",  "7")
    };

    var dict = tuples
       .ToLookup(tuple => tuple.Item2, tuple => tuple.Item1)
       .ToDictionary(tuple => tuple.Key, string.Concat);

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", dict));
}
```